# NHibernate Configuration

Tags: c#, nhibernate, configuration

My NHibernate configuration is set up using hibernate.cfg.xml, and now I am trying to implement Rhino.Seucrity, and for its configuration I need to retrieve a NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration instance. Now i was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the configuration instance that hibernate.cfg.xml produces?

Comment: Have you placed NHibernate-configuration section in web.config or in a seperate file?

Comment: Well, somewhere in your code you must be creating the Configuration object and building the ISessionFactory. Get it from there...

Comment: @dotjoe OMG, im the biggest idiot ever! Post that as an answer so i can accept it :) I didnt realise Configuration implements ISessionFactory, i thought they were completely sepereate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, somewhere in your code you must be creating the Configuration object and building the ISessionFactory. Get it from there...